# does elastic-mq have a health/readiness port?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, elastic-mq

I am writing a helm chart for a project that will load `softwaremill/elasticmq-native` and want to check that its ready (liveness/readiness).

I found no information regarding any such endpoints for `elastic-mq`, am I missing something? currently I just use 9325 (ui port).